# Positioning a div at the bottom of a “absolute” <div>

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I'm having troubles positioning my divs. I want to have my `child` div stick to the bottom of the `parent` div, with `grandchild_1` and `grandchild_2` staying correctly put. By that, I mean having `grandchild_1` before `grandchild_2`, like on the picture.

This is what I've tried, but the "child" div sticks to the top :

```
#parent {
   position: relative;
}

#child {
   position: absolute; bottom: 0;
}



<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="grandchild_1">
        </div>
        <div id="grandchild_2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Anyone knows how I should proceed ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a height on the parent it will stick to the bottom.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGqzVd

## HTML

```
<div id="parent">
  Parent
  <div id="child">
    Child
    <div id="grandchild_1">
      Grandchild 1
    </div>
    <div id="grandchild_2">
      Grandchild 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
div {
  padding: 5px;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}

#grandchild_1 {
  background: pink;
}

#grandchild_2 {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code works as is...assuming that the parent has a height greater than that of the child.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}
#grandchild_1,
#grandchild_2 {
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grandchild_1">GC1
    </div>
    <div id="grandchild_2">GC2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As an alternative to positioning, flexbox can do the same...***and the child will affect the height of the parent which an absolutely positioned child cannot***.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#child {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
#grandchild_1,
#grandchild_2 {
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grandchild_1">GC1
    </div>
    <div id="grandchild_2">GC2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```